# How to keep four buttons in the same row when resized?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to implement a simple browsergame to learn webddevelopment. I have a group of divs with which I want to represent a warrior. Here I have a Button group with 4 buttons at the Head of the "div table". The problem is that the 4 buttons are not shown in the same row when the screen gets smaller. Another problem is that there are white spaces between the buttons but I want them to fill the whole button group dynamically. So if there are two buttons then they shall fill out the button group too. Can anyone help?

Here is my jsfiddle:

```css
.div-TableHeadName {
  padding-top:6px;
  height:35px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.div-TableHeadClass {
  padding-top:6px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height:35px;
}
.div-TableBodyImage{
  height:160px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.div-TableBodyDescription{
    height: 160px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.btn--actionType{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  height: 35px;
  width: 25%
}

.btn--actionType:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
.btn--performAction{
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  color: white;
  height: 35px;
  width: 25%
}
.btn--group{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="div-Table">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 div-TableHeadName">
      <span>Guldan</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4 div-TableHeadClass">
      <span>Warrior</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <btn-group data-toggle="buttons" class="btn--group">
        <div class="btn btn--actionType">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="action" value="sword"/>Sword
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn--actionType">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="action" value="axe"/>Axe
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn--actionType">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="action" value="bow"/>Bow
          </label>
        </div>
        <div type="button" class="btn btn--performAction">Attack
        </div>
      </btn-group>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="padding-top:10px" class="col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2 div-TableBodyImage">  
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/b/b1/Portrait_placeholder.png" width="100"/>
  </div>
  <div style="padding: 10px" class="col-md-10 col-sm-10 col-xs-10 div-TableBodyDescription">
    <span>This is a description for Guldan, an orc warrior.</span>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: It seems unusual to have radio buttons look like regular buttons. I would not consider that to be good UX.  Just my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.div-TableHeadName {
  padding-top:6px;
  height:35px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
}
.div-TableHeadClass {
  padding-top:6px;
  background-color: darkgrey;
  height:35px;
}
.div-TableBodyImage{
  height:160px;
  background-color: lightgrey;
}
.div-TableBodyDescription{
    height: 160px;
    background-color: lightgrey;
}
.btn--actionType{
  background-color: lightgrey;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  height: 35px;
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
}

.btn--actionType:hover{
  background-color: red;
}
.btn--performAction{
  background-color: black;
  border-radius: 0 !important;
  color: white;
  height: 35px;
  width: 25%
}
.btn--group{
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="div-Table">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      <btn-group data-toggle="buttons" class="btn--group">
        <div class="btn btn--actionType">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="action" value="sword"/>Sword
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn--actionType">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="action" value="axe"/>Axe
          </label>
        </div>
        <div class="btn btn--actionType">
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="action" value="bow"/>Bow
          </label>
        </div>
        <div type="button" class="btn btn--performAction">Attack
        </div>
      </btn-group>
    </div>  
  </div>    
</body>
```

Sometimes reducing your problem to just the elements that matter can help you solve the issue.  I have done that in the code you see.  Turns out that float the buttons instead of "inline-block" fixes both issues you are having.  Inline-block specifically adds some space in there, floating does not.  Also it is the extra space that is causing your 25% buttons to wrap.